# How can I create a default project in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried to create a project to my Google Cloud, after the following suggestion during the process of configuration :

*This account has no projects. 

Would you like to create one? (Y/n)?  Y*

After that it asked to insert a PROJECT ID, and so I did as it follows :

*Enter a Project ID. Note that a Project ID CANNOT be changed later.

Project IDs must be 6-30 characters (lowercase ASCII, digits, or
hyphens) in length and start with a lowercase letter. **gcloud projects create LINUX_CLOUD_LEARNING***

```
gcloud projects create LINUX_CLOUD_LEARNING
```

The command above it was my choice, and then I received the following return :

```
> *WARNING: Project creation failed: HttpError accessing <https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?alt=json>:
> response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type':
> 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Sat, 29 Aug 2020 16:07:42
> GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection':
> '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options':
> 'nosniff', 'server-timing': 'gfet4t7; dur=727', 'alt-svc':
> 'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443";
> ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443";
> ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443";
> ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'transfer-encoding':
> 'chunked', 'status': '400', 'content-length': '1028',
> '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{   "error": {
>     "code": 400,
>     "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
>     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
>     "details": [
>       {
>         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
>         "fieldViolations": [
>           {
>             "field": "project_id",
>             "description": "project_id must be at most 30 characters long"
>           },
>           {
>             "field": "project_id",
>             "description": "project_id contains invalid characters"
>           },
>           {
>             "field": "display_name",
>             "description": "project display name must be at most 30 characters"
>           },
>           {
>             "field": "display_name",
>             "description": "project display name contains invalid characters"
>           }
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
>         "links": [
>           {
>             "url": "https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects"
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     ]   } }
> > Please make sure to create the project [gcloud projects create LINUX_CLOUD_LEARINING] using
>     $ gcloud projects create gcloud projects create LINUX_CLOUD_LEARINING or change to another project using
>     $ gcloud config set project <PROJECT ID>*
```

Why this happened and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the prerequisite and error display is self-explanatory - [the project ID can only contain lowercase letters, digits or hyphens](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#before_you_begin). Change `gcloud projects create LINUX_CLOUD_LEARNING` to `gcloud projects create linux-cloud-learning` or similar, and if that project ID doesn't already exist you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the documentation [1] that Google provides you will notice that lowercase letters,numbers and hyphens are allowed characters. The underscore is not permitted , try renaming the project with something other than underscores. Remember as well the Project Id must start with a lowercase letter, and cannot have a trailing hyphen

[1] Before you begin :
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#before_you_begin